# Issues for formbased autentication for Wordpress Blog on IIS using Sqlserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, wordpress, single-sign-on

I have configured the wordpress using phanlager on IIS and sqlserver. I am trying to use the formbased authentication on my blog site so when user logged into the parent site then there shouldn't be any need of login into wordpress.

Parent **main site** is running on **ASP.NET MVC** and implemented the form based authentication on it. Now i want that parent site users can access the wordpress blog as well.

for this i used following link to configure my settings.

http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2012/wordpress-on-dotnet-with-sql-server-using-phalanger-3-0

Now for single sign on i am trying to use the following plugin

http://mvolo.com/iis-authentication-plugin-for-the-wordpress-php-blogging-engine/

and the above plug in giving me the error

```
wp_get_cookie_login is deprecated since version 2.5 with no alternative available
```

For blogging i may consider orchard if wordpress will not going to work as a blogging engine. Any help how to configure formbased autentication for Wordpress Blog on IIS using Sqlserver or I should consider the orchard cms instead.

---

Regards,

Comment: i tried the following way to solve the things  but it is limited to reading the aspxauth cookie and then redirect to aspx page for reading the cookie and authenticating the user. http://www.silverclaw.net/?p=273

Comment: http://www.silverclaw.net/?p=273 in this solution i tried to configure on chrome but sometime plugin code can't access the aspxauth cookie.